# extract custom date/time from a date variable

Tags: java, date, time

How can I shorten the following date below to something like Thursday 19th September

```
java.util.Date t = MoonPhaseFinder.findFullMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance());
```

the above code prints as follow

```
Thu Sep 19 21:34:21 EST 2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try on this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd'th' MMMM");
System.out.println(sdf.format(t));
```